# Federation Metadata containing wrong SSL

Tags: iis, adfs, adfs2.0

Running into a bit of an issue with ADFS/IIS, I have an IIS server and a ADFS server.

They are named as follows:

Iis-001.contoso.com
ADFS.contoso.com

I have updated my Microsoft CRM certificate on the IIS server and also imported it like you should on the ADFS server. However the issue is it won’t work. I’m getting the error

“An error occurred during an attempt to read the federation metadata”

I can open it in the browser fine on both servers so communication doesn’t appear to be an issue, however I have noticed that under the certificate section of the XML file it still shows the old certificate. How would one go about regenerating the FederationMetadata.XML

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You might try to share some screen shots to indicate clearly what you are talking about.

Comment: I can’t share any screenshots it’s private data, however the federationmetadata is supposed to be pulled from the IIS server, but the information in it is incorrect, still containing old certificates data

Comment: try to restart the adfs service. please share the detailed error message snapshot.

Comment: What certificate shows in the certificate tab in the ADFS wizard?